# Fixing character count, decimal count, and "0" character count in swift

Tags: swift, uikit

When I run this code, I can only insert the "." once. If it is already in one of the text fields I can't use another "." in another text field, this is the same with the character count. If 8 characters are entered in one text field no characters can be entered in any of the other text fields.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {    
            // cost of materials
        if (costOfMaterialsTXT.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
                return false
        }
            // tech hours
        if (techHoursTXT.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
            return false
        }
            // helper hours
        if (helperHoursTXT.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
                return false
        }
        //Prevent "0" characters as the first characters
        
            // cost of materials
        if (costOfMaterialsTXT.text == "0" && string.isEmpty)  {

                return true
        } else if (costOfMaterialsTXT.text == "0" && string != ".") {
                return false
        }
            // tech hours
        if (techHoursTXT.text == "0" && string.isEmpty)  {
            return true
        
        } else if (techHoursTXT.text == "0" && string != ".") {
            return false
        }
            // helper hours
        if (helperHoursTXT.text == "0" && string.isEmpty)  {

                return true
        } else if (helperHoursTXT.text == "0" && string != ".") {
                    return false
        }

        //Limit the character count to 8
            
            // cost of materials
        if ((costOfMaterialsTXT.text!) + string).count > 8 {
                return false
        }
            // tech hours
        if ((techHoursTXT.text!) + string).count > 8 {
            return false
        }
            // helper hours
        if ((helperHoursTXT.text!) + string).count > 8 {
                return false
        }

        // Only Numbers And Decimal-Point Allowed
        let allowedCharacters = "0123456789."
        let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
        let typedCharactersSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

        return allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharactersSet)
    }
```

Comment: And you want to be able to be able to put a "." only once in EACH textField? If so, read the `textField` parameter of the delegate method. It will let you know which one is currently being edited, so you shouldn't focus on the others.

Comment: yes that is correct, once a calculation occurs, it will turn it into a currency format, so it would crash if there are multiple ".", i.e. 1..2 instead of just 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {    

    guard [costOfMaterialsTXT, techHoursTXT, helperHoursTXT].contains(textField) else { 
        return true //It's another textfield, is it even possible? Do you have more textField?
    }
    
    if (textField.text?.contains("."))! && string == "." {
        return false
    }
    //Prevent "0" characters as the first characters
    if (textField.text == "0" && string.isEmpty)  {
        return true  
    } else if (textField.text == "0" && string != ".") {
        return false
    }
    
    //Limit the character count to 8
    if ((textField.text!) + string).count > 8 {
        return false
    }
    
    let allowedCharacters = "0123456789."
    let allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: allowedCharacters)
    let typedCharactersSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    
    return allowedCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: typedCharactersSet)
}
```

Here's the minima factorization.

You check at start if it's one of your `UITextField` with that behavior. Read the `textField` parameter.
You do the SAME behavior for each `UITextField`, so you shouldn't care about `costOfMaterialsTXT`, `techHoursTXT`, nor `helperHoursTXT`, it's any of these `UITextField`.

Now, about the code in itself...

You can remove the guard at the beginning if you only have those 3.
You should unwrap correctly here `textField.text?.contains("."))!` and `textField.text!`. What if `string` is "./.." (from a copy/paste) for instance?

Comment: thank you this is very helpful, it solved my issue!! It is already prevented from copy and paste

Comment: still getting into coding and the way you explained this makes total sense now